# Redraw control flow line on dragging the block

Tags: java, swt, controls, eclipse-rcp, draggable

I am doing a project on eclipse RCP(Rich Client Platform), I want to design an stand alone gui application, where I will have two blocks linked with control flow line, and those blocks must be draggable. When I drag any of the blocks, the control flow line must redraw and it should not loose link with other block. Is there any framework available to accomplish this process? Please help me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should have a look at [Draw2d](http://www.eclipse.org/gef/draw2d/) or [Zest](http://www.eclipse.org/gef/zest/).

[Here](http://nyssen.blogspot.co.uk/2010/12/draw2d-examples-hidden-treasure.html) are a couple of examples for Draw2d:

[image]

[Here](http://wiki.eclipse.org/GEF_Zest_Visualization) is an example for Zest.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

If it is only this type of simple model you want to accomplish, take a look at Draw2D.
If you are pushing this further, look at both GEF or GMF, which allows you to construct the same but from a more abstract view.